# Creating Wrapper for App Component in React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I need to somehow access my Redux store from App.js , from the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/) it say that i can create new entry point for my App , so I did create one but somehow my App still couldnt access the Redux Store.

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

Here is My **App.js** Code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

//Layout
import Auth from "./src/layout/Auth.layout";
import Register from "./src/layout/Register.layout";
import Drawer from "./src/navigation/Drawer";
export default function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    DMSans: require("./assets/fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf"),
    "DMSans-Medium": require("./assets/fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf"),
    "DMSans-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf"),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded || isLoading) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        {!isLoggedIn ? (
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Auth"
            screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={Auth} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <Drawer />
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

here is my **EntryPoint.js** that i have created :

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import App from "../App";
import React from "react";
import { store, persistor } from "./state/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/es/integration/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export default function EntryPoint() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

registerRootComponent(EntryPoint);
```

What am I missing here ? or there's better solution that I can implement ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I ended up removing the EntryPoint.js and create a wrapper inside my App.js instead.

**App.js** code :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

//Layout
import Auth from "./src/layout/Auth.layout";
import Register from "./src/layout/Register.layout";
import Drawer from "./src/navigation/Drawer";
import { store, persistor } from "./src/state/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/es/integration/react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const AppWrapper = () => {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    DMSans: require("./assets/fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf"),
    "DMSans-Medium": require("./assets/fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf"),
    "DMSans-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf"),
  });
  if (!fontsLoaded || isLoading) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        {!isLoggedIn ? (
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Auth"
            screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={Auth} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <Drawer />
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <AppWrapper />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```